# Why does Ruby Kirbybase doesn't work with if statement?

Tags: ruby, database

I recently started using kirbybase in ruby, but I ran into a problem using the if statement with a result set. Here's a semplified code that seems to have this problem:

```
require 'kirbybase'

db = KirbyBase.new
if db.table_exists?(:database)
db.drop_table(:database)
end

list = db.create_table(:database, :name, :String, :password, :String, :test, :String)

name = 'Test'
password = 'abcde'

list.insert(name, password, nil)

account = list.select { |r| r.name == name}

if account.test.nil?
 puts 'right'
else
 puts 'wrong'
end
```

Why does it output "wrong"?

Comment: can you check with account.test.empty? or account.test.blank?

Comment: With account.test.empty? it says:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
test.rb:17:in `<main>': undefined method `blank?' for [nil]:Array (NoMethodError)


With account.test.blank? again "wrong"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be strange to answer my own question but I solved the problem: account.test  is an array so the correct form of the if statement is:

```
if account.test[0].nil?
 puts 'right'
else
 puts 'wrong'
end
```